# Safe way to call a method for each element of a set that modifies said set?

Tags: c#, hashset

I've got a class defined like this (relevant methods shown):

```
class ShaderProgram : IDisposable
{
    private HashSet<Shader> _shaders = new HashSet<Shader>();

    public void AttachShader(Shader shader)
    {
        GL.AttachShader(Handle, shader.Handle);
        _shaders.Add(shader);
    }

    public void DetachShader(Shader shader)
    {
        GL.DetachShader(Handle, shader.Handle);
        _shaders.Remove(shader);
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to write the `Dispose` method, I thought I could do it like this:

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach(var shader in _shaders)
            DetachShader(shader);
        GL.DeleteProgram(Handle);
    }
```

But now I suspect that's unsafe because I'm iterating over a set and deleting from it at the same time... if it were a queue or stack Id just say "while not empty, pop one off and delete it", but since it's a HashSet... I'm not sure what the best approach is. How should I handle this?

**Edit:** The point is to avoid code duplication; I want to call `ShaderProgram.DetachShader` for each element. I know I can *repeat* the code inside that function and then clear the whole set at the end -- that's not what I want to do.

---

Occurs to me now, that I don't really have to empty the HashSet at all, do I? The `ShaderProgram` object is about to be destroyed anyway, all I need to do is clean up any unmanaged resources, and the C# GC can clean up the rest, right?

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var shader in _shaders)
            GL.DetachShader(Handle, shader.Handle);
        GL.DeleteProgram(Handle);
    }
```

That said, I still want answers to the original question. My goal here is not to solve a very simple problem, but to learn the best approach to this class of problem.

Answer (score 2):

How about some LINQ:

```
while (_shaders.Any()) {
    DetachShader(_shaders.First());
}
```

This wouldn't work in general, though, because you could end up calling the function on the same element multiple times. It only makes sense if the function is removing the element from the underlying collection.

In the general case, where the function doesn't modify the collection, you could use something like this:

```
while (hashset.Any()) {
    var item = hashset.First();
    Process(item);

    hashset.Remove(item);
}
```

Or this:

```
foreach (var item in hashset) {
    Process(item);
}

hashset.Clear();
```

**Update:** As pointed out by @SLaks in the comments, calling `First()` for every element in the hash set as it's emptied is O(n^2). This doesn't matter for tiny collections, but could make a world of difference if you have a large collection.

Comment: @SLaks: You specifically mean repeatedly calling `.First()`; not LINQ in general, right? Thanks.

Comment: @Mark: Yes.  LINQ in general is very fast.

Comment: @SLaks: Oho, didn't know that. Thanks! Performance wouldn't be an issue except with larger hash sets, though.

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem in doing this, but maybe you should consider to iterate your set, detach your shader from your GL variable and then just clear your HashSet. If you don't want to duplicate code that's in your own detach method you should split that one up and let it be called from those 2 places.

Comment: Actually, the OP is invoking undefined behaviour. From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341120.aspx): "If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and its behavior is undefined." Good point about separating the code, though; +1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't break a thing if you don't remove elements at random positions. But if the docs warn for undefined behaviour it's better not do so. Thanks for clearing it out.

Comment: Yeah... I'm trying to avoid duplicate code; I don't know what else might go in there yet.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand how come someone with 17k reputation is asking this. Am I missing something?

```
public void Dispose()
{
    foreach(var shader in _shaders)
        GL.DetachShader( Handle, shader.Handle );
    _shaders.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Missing bit is you did not check his tags, he is mainly into PHP , JQuery , Javascript etc and Dispose() is sometimes even confused by GC ;)

Comment: @MikeNakis: I thought of that; the point was the avoid code duplication. I wanted to call `this.DetachShader`. The implementation is simple now, but what if I wanted to expand it?

Comment: OK, I thought that what gets duplicated is a single call, so no big deal. Of course, if you want to expand that in the future, then you will need a private cleanup_this_shader() helper method invoked both by your Dispose() and by your DetachShader().

Answer (score 1):

If your collection is very small I would use:

```
foreach (var item in set.ToArray())
     set.Remove(item);
```

Another solution would be the `RemoveWhere()` method:

```
set.RemoveWhere(item =>
{
     Console.WriteLine(item);
     return true;
});
```

Comment: Huh? What does casting the set to an array first accomplish? And how does this solve my problem? I need to call "DetachShader" for each item in the list.

Comment: If you remove items from a collection while iterating over it. `AsArray()` will create another collection, containing the same elements as `list`. You can iterate over the array and remove the elements safely from your list/set.

Comment: Ohhh...if I make a copy of the set, then I can modify the original set without fear. That wasn't very clear from your examples :) `HashSet` doesn't have `RemoveAll` but it does have `RemoveWhere` which seems to do the same thing. Sneaky.

Comment: Aww, sorry!! My fault :) I will correct this as soon as I can restart my Visual Studio :)

Comment: You mean `ToArray()`, not `AsArray()` ;-)

Comment: @Cameron: Damn :) you're right. whats wrong today.. Thank you!